# unhandled Exception - throws is not working

Tags: java

In a test case, I have the line

```
ZahlPasstNicht zahlPasstNicht = new ZahlPasstNicht(min, max, ist);
```

The second part is underlined red and it says: **Unhandled Exception: ZahlPasstNicht**

I could use try/catch or let the constructor throw an error, I tried to do the latter:

```
public class ZahlPasstNicht extends IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    public ZahlPasstNicht(int a, int b, int c) throws ZahlPasstNicht {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is an odd use case. There's zero chance of an exception being thrown, and exception classes shouldn't throw exceptions.

Comment: I foresee an infinite loop if you manage to cause an exception of type `ZahlPasstNicht` while constructing a `ZahlPasstNicht`... I once saw a system that was throwing an error while logging an error which caused it to log an error... The log file exploded to 50Gb.

Comment: In addition, it's bad practice to put `throws RuntimeException`, which `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is a `RuntimeException`.  Unchecked exceptions do not require a `throws`. Only put `throws` for checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in provided code. Technically it is correct but not logically. You can see that it is working fine.[You can see working code here](https://ideone.com/TxxXRV).

**Note:** Since in `ideone`, I was allowed to code in only a single file, so `ZahlPasstNicht` class is not made public here.

Code is **logically incorrect** because:

- It is declared that constructor `ZahlPasstNicht` is throwing `ZahlPasstNicht` but there is no code which throws exception of type `ZahlPasstNicht` in constructor of `ZahlPasstNicht`.
- Also if you throw exception of type `ZahlPasstNicht` in constructor `ZahlPasstNicht` then it will fall into infinite loop.

The problem seems in any other part of the code. Make sure that argument of constructor `ZahlPasstNicht` are compatible i.e. variable `min`, `max` and `ist` are of type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any case in which it would make sense to put a throws clause in the constructor of an exception class, since an exception class should not throw another exception (and especially not itself) when it is instantiated.

Just write

```
public ZahlPasstNicht(int a, int b, int c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}
```

And normally you wouldn't instantiate an exception class if you are not going to throw it.

This doesn't make much sense:

```
ZahlPasstNicht zahlPasstNicht = new ZahlPasstNicht(min, max, ist);
```

This does:

```
throw new ZahlPasstNicht(min, max, ist);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ZahlPasstNicht(int a, int b, int c) throws ZahlPasstNicht
```

Your constructor specifies that it can `throw` but you call it outside a `try` block therefore the exception would be unhandled.

I don't think you need the `throw` part in this case.